# how can I draw the pushdown automaton for a language

Tags: context-free-grammar

How can I draw the pushdown automaton for the language $\{w \in \{a,b,c\}^{*}:w \text{ is of the form } y c y^{R}, y \in \{a,b\}^{*}\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - let's call the starting state COPY
> - on input character $a$ or $b$, PUSH this into the stack and stay on state COPY
> - if character $c$ is the input, move to state CHECK
> - from state CHECK, input $c$ leads to state ERROR
> - similarly, both cases (tape: $a$, POP: $b$), $\ $(tape: $b$, POP $a$) lead to state ERROR
> - the other two inputs (tape: $a$, POP: $a$), $\ $(tape: $b$, POP $b$) stay on state CHECK
> - finally (tape: *EOT*, POP: empty) goes to state ACCEPT

Comment: I will post it as an answer,so that you can see if that what I have drawn is right.

Answer (score 1):

That's what I have tried.Do you mean that I should do something like that?

[image]

Comment: Yes, something like that.
I don't exactly know how  a stack (pushdown) automaton is pictured usually, I mean how to indicate the PUSH/POP informations and how to distinguish the stack input (POP) from the tape input in the drawing...

Comment: If I want to show that a language is accepted by a pushdown automaton,do I have to draw one or could I just write something like that,what you have written in your previous post?

Comment: if you write it down, it's usually clearer. If the exercise was specifically to draw, then add some picture..